# Setting Querystring option for Hub connection in Angular SignalR

Tags: connection, signalr, query-string, signalr-hub

We are using @aspnet/signalR library in our angular application. Is there a way to set the query string property so that querystring sent with all the signalR requests ? Similar to how we can do in jquery using $.connection.hub.qs.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the querystring as part of the connection url and it will persist across requests.

`let connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://app/hubroute?customQS=1")
    .build();`